# Who serial downvoted me?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

I was a victim of serial downvoting 2 days ago. Is it possible to know the username, IP address or similar of the person who down-voted me? What happens to such people? Will they be banned/warned?

Comment: The marked duplicate isn't a duplicate.  It is effectively asking how to report the serial downvoting.   This question is asking about what happens after you report it, or after the script finds an instance of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will not be told the username or IP address of someone who has downvoted you, whether serially or not.

They may or may not be banned or given a moderator warning depending on the context, however in the case of automatic vote reversal, no punishments are given by default.  You will not be told, for any particular instance, what moderation action was taken in that case (this applies to most any type of offense, not just voting fraud); that is between the offender and the moderators.  However, if a user is suspended, it will state that they are suspended on their profile, although the exact reason for the suspension is not public information.

Comment: Thanks. The serial voting was reversed and granted the rapport back. There should be some way of viewing such people so that it prevents serial down/up voting for some extent. But I'm happy in a way because someone out there is pissed of by my work ;)... huh!

Comment: "Rapport"? You mean "reputation"?

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce: oh! sorry yes I mean the reputation.

Answer (score 12):

No, absolutely not. Voting is anonymous, even in cases of voting fraud. There is no way for a regular user to retrieve **any** identifying information about the person who cast the votes.

Currently, nothing happens to the user. Unless a moderator was directly involved in reversing the votes, they won't receive any sort of notification or warning about the votes. Most cases of serial voting reversals are quite minor and don't require any action on the part of moderators or warrant any such warning.